# Does not redirect to home page on successRedirect of Passport with ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, bcrypt

***UPDATE***: *I figured out that `await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)` in passport.js file is always false. that's why its not going to the if condition. But why its always false.*

I am new to NodeJs. I created a registration/login page using MySQL, ExpressJs, and Passport. But after a successful login attempt the code is not redirecting to the page to home page as I intended to do. It just lands to login page again which I wanted in case of failureRedirect. I must be doing something wrong.
This is how my **passport.js** config looks like:

```
const LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt")


function initialize(passport, getUserByEmail, getUserById) {
    // Function to authenticate users
    const authenticateUsers = async(email, password, done) => {
        // Get users by email
        const user = await getUserByEmail(email)
        console.log(user)
        if (user == null) {
            return done(null, false, { message: "User is not registered" })
        }
        try {
            if (await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)) {
                return done(null, user)
            } else {
                return done(null, false, { message: "Wrong credential(s)" })
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
            return done(e)
        }
    }

    passport.use(new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'email' }, authenticateUsers))
    passport.serializeUser((user, done) => done(null, user.id))
    passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
        return done(null, getUserById(id))
    })
}

module.exports = initialize
```

And this is the **server.js** code

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") {
    require("dotenv").config()
}

const express = require("express")
const db = require("./config/database")
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt")
const { Prisma } = require("@prisma/client")
const initializePassport = require("./config/passport")
const flash = require("express-flash")
const session = require("express-session")
const { application } = require("express")
const passport = require("passport")
const server = express()

initializePassport(
        passport,
        async email => await db.user.findFirst({ where: { email } }),
        async id => await db.user.findFirst({ where: { id } })
    )

server.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false })) //this code is to get the form data in req.body
server.use(flash())
server.use(session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false, // we want to resave the session variable if nothing is changed
    saveUninitialized: false
}))
server.use(passport.initialize())
server.use(passport.session())


async function main() {
    const PORT = 8080

    server.listen(PORT, function() {
        console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}...`)
    })
}

server.get('/', async(req, res) => {
    res.render("index.ejs")
})

server.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    res.render('login.ejs')
})

server.post('/login', passport.authenticate("local", {

    successRedirect: "/",
    failureRedirect: "/login",
    failureFlash: true
}))

server.get('/registration', (req, res) => {
    res.render('registration.ejs')
})

server.post('/registration', async(req, res) => {
    // console.log(req.body)
    const encryptedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password.toString(), 10)
    const { firstName, lastName, email } = req.body
    console.log(firstName, lastName, email, encryptedPassword)
    if (email && encryptedPassword) {
        try {
            //db.promise().query(`INSERT INTO user (email, password, firstName, lastName) VALUES('${email}','${encryptedPassword}','${firstName}','${lastName}')`)
            const result = await db.user.create({
                data: { email: email, password: encryptedPassword, firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName }
            })
            console.log(result);
            //res.status(201).send({ message: "User is created" })
            res.redirect("/login")
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
            res.redirect("/registration")
        } finally {
            await db.$disconnect();
        }

    }
})

main();
```

I am stuck at this point as I couldn't find any tutorials specifically for the issue I am facing. Any help or hint will be appreciated..please :)

Here is the **login** view page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Login</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <style>
            .main {
                background-color: #EAF7FF;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100vh;
                margin: auto;
            }
            
            .form-container {
                background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
                max-width: 500px;
                margin: 0 auto;
                padding: 30px;
                border: 1px solid #ccc;
                border-radius: 10px;
                box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc;
            }
            
            .btn {
                background-color: #4F95FF;
                width: 100px;
                border-radius: 14px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="form-container">
                <form action="/login" method="POST">
                    <h2 class="text-center">Login</h2>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group form-check">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="remember-me">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="remember-me">Remember me</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-rounded btn-lg">Login</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <p>Don't have an account?
                            <a href="registration"> Register</p>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you please share some UI code? From where you are making this request

Comment: @RahulPatil You mean the ejs files?

Comment: added to the end of original post @RahulPatil

Comment: I figured out that `await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)` is always false. that's why its not going to the if condition. But why its always false.